# What do the numbers below the notes mean in violin music?

Tags: sheet-music, violin

[image: Violin score]

I know that the numbers above the notes are the fingerings, but what are the numbers below the notes? Also what do the brackets mean?

Comment: I don’t know for certain, but since they go from 1 to 4 and the lower notes generally have lower numbers, the most likely explanation is they are suggested left hand fingerings for the notes. 1 is the index finger and 4 is the little finger. The Roman numerals are probably suggested playing positions on the neck. Not sure about the brackets. Perhaps alternate options.

Comment: @ToddWilcox In orchestral string notation, Roman numerals indicate what string to play on. I indicates the highest string; IV indicates the lowest. It’s confusing, because it’s the opposite of guitar notation, where Roman numerals indicate the fret number and Arabic numerals in circles represent the string.

Answer (score 7):

The numbers below the staff are alternative fingerings. If you are referring to the brackets above the staff, they show when you are to remain on the string indicated by the Roman numerals (IV=G etc.)

Answer (score -1):

So yes your very much correct something like this [image]

The circled numbers represents where to put your finger over the G (IV) string.